# Titanium pass image to a canvas

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have an image on disk that I would like to load into a html canvas. I have searched but cannot find any info on doing this. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? From what directory / disk are you trying to load the image from (Application Data, Temp Directory, Resources Directory)? Are you trying to draw on the image or manipulate it or will it just be a background? There are multiple solutions to this and extra clarification on the use case will help me with a better answer.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. I wish to be able to download an image with HTTPClient, save it, then load into the canvas for manipulation. i.e. drawing on top of the image. Thanks